# How can I launch a simple Flow from APEX?

Tags: apex, flow

All I want to do is launch my flow from APEX so ultimately I can schedule it. Everywhere else seems to be doing something more complicated with VF pages. Here's my code below.

```
public class FlowController {

    public Flow.Interview.RenewalOpptyGenerationFlow myFlow {get; set;}

    public void start() {
        Flow.Interview.RenewalOpptyGenerationFlow myFlow;
        myFlow.start();
        String outputValue = (String) myFlow.getVariableValue('newOpportunityList');
        System.debug(newOpportunityList);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're new to apex, try some of the [Developer Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trail/force_com_dev_beginner). They're an excellent way to get accustomed to the platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this recent [question illustrated](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/apex-variable-map-values-passed-to-auto-launched-flow-not-recognized-by-flow), you need to instantiate the flow:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
Flow.Interview.RenewalOpptyGenerationFlow myFlow = new Flow.Interview.RenewalOpptyGenerationFlow(params);
myFlow.start();
...
```

Also see [Calling Flow from Apex](https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/10/26/calling-flow-from-apex/) for more explanation.