# Supply sObject record to process builder flow via REST API

Tags: rest-api, process-builder, visual-workflow, action, invocable-method

I'm trying to invoke a custom flow (built via process builder) via REST API.

The process begins with a contact record,

> This process starts when another process invokes it.
>
> Select an object
> to associate with the process:
>
> Contact

The unique API name of the process is my_process.

I am trying to post a contact record into this custom action, like so:

```
url = instance_url +'/services/data/v33.0/actions/custom/flow/my_process'

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}

payload = {
    'inputs': [{
        'sObjectId': '0034F000005RUTOQG5' 
    }]
}
```

The response is:

```
[
   {
      "actionName":"my_process",
      "errors":[
         {
            "statusCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION",
            "message":"The flow doesn't have a variable with the name sObjectId, or the variable doesn't allow input access.",
            "fields":[

            ]
         }
      ],
      "isSuccess":false,
      "outputValues":null
   }
]
```

I did check that the flow is available, via GET request to:

`/services/data/v33.0/actions/custom/flow`

and it did show my_process.

How can I supply the contact value to the flow via the REST api?

Thank you!

For reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_flow.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_actions_invocable_custom.htm

EDIT: tried changing the key to 'recordId'

```
'inputs': [{
        'recordId': '0034F000005RUTOQG5' 
    }]
```

based on:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_internal_action.htm

same error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh man... of course, it was a case issue.

here is the proper *casing* for the post payload:

```
payload = {
    'inputs': [{
        'SObjectId': '0034F000005RUTOQG5' 
    }]
}
```

SObjectId vs sObjectId

`(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻`

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/apex-variable-map-values-passed-to-auto-launched-flow-not-recognized-by-flow -- I remember running into this myself