# Can't get flow variable from flow interview I created and started in Apex

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, variable, flow-interviews

Having come across [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_visualworkflow_vars.htm) that states that flow variables can be retrieved for a specific flow in Apex, I tested this by writing the following code:

```
myEvent__e eventRecord = new myEvent__e(
    myBoolean__c = true,
    myText__c = 'my message'
);
Flow.Interview myFlowInterview = Flow.Interview.createInterview('myFlow',new Map<String, Object>{ 'platformEventRecord' => eventRecord });
myFlowInterview.start();
System.debug(myFlowInterview.getVariableValue('platformEventRecord'));
```

*myFlow* is an autolaunched flow with a myEvent__e-type record variable available for input called *platformEventRecord*. I expected eventRecord would be returned when I ran getVariableValue() but I got null instead despite the specified variable being in the flow. Is my code wrong or is getVariableValue() not meant to be used in such a case? I have a feeling it is the latter but is it the fact that I am passing a record that this isn't working? Is it something else? Considering the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/flow_interview_class.htm#flow_interview_class) states as follows,

> **getVariableValue(variableName)**
> *Returns the value of the specified flow variable. The flow variable can be in the flow embedded in the Visualforce page, or in a separate flow that is called by a subflow element.*

does this mean this method only works if the flow and its subflow if present is embedded in a VF page?

Comment: is the variable available for output too?

Comment: could be [case sensitive issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/apex-variable-map-values-passed-to-auto-launched-flow-not-recognized-by-flow)

Comment: @cropredy I have confirmed the variable names are exactly the same.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Your tip did the trick. When I made the variable available for output as well, I was able to get back the value that was passed in. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your flow variable is available for both output and input.

This is likely to fix your issue.