# NextBestAction isRecommendationAccepted Variable

Tags: einstein-next-best-action

A coworker and I are looking at [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nba_launch_flow_accepts_rejects.htm&type=5) about when launching a flow when a next best action is accepted or rejected from the Next Best Action lightning component on a page. It mentions an input variable `isRecommendationAccepted`.

My question is how does that get set?

- Does Salesforce automagically set it based on what the user clicked?
- I assume that would make the variable name `isRecommendationAccepted` a "special" name, such as recordId.
- I don't see anyplace in the properties on the lightning component to
  set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES - it is a special input variable that if you want the flow that executes as a result of an accept/reject to know which option the user chose.

SFDC sets the Boolean variable field to true if the user "accepted" the NBA recommendation; otherwise it is set to false. It is not required

Comment: Thanks for confirming. We discovered the issue: we had IsRecommendationAccepted instead of isRecommendationAccepted, and apparently, case matters, as changing it to isRecommendationAccepted worked. Strange, as I Apex variables are case-insensitive. You would think that would hold true in flows.

Comment: yep - flow input and output variables are case sensitive - [see this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/apex-variable-map-values-passed-to-auto-launched-flow-not-recognized-by-flow/145552#145552)